# Create undo and redo function

Tags: python, tkinter

In this code, lines created by mouse button in the canvas. With the help of Undo and Redo button remove these lines.
I also want to add UNDO/REDO to the Invoker so that I can go backawards and forwards through time.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
my_canvas = Canvas(root, bg = "white", height=500, width=500, cursor="cross")
#Draw Line using mouse
coords = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "x2": 0, "y2": 0}
final = []
lines = []

def click(e):
    coords["x"] = e.x
    coords["y"] = e.y
    lines.append(my_canvas.create_line(coords["x"], coords["y"], coords["x"], coords["y"], fill='red', width=2))

def release(l):
    lis = []
    lis.append(coords["x"]);
    lis.append(coords["y"]);
    lis.append(coords["x2"]);
    lis.append(coords["x2"])
    final.append(lis)


def drag(e):
    coords["x2"] = e.x
    coords["y2"] = e.y
    my_canvas.coords(lines[-1], coords["x"], coords["y"], coords["x2"], coords["y2"])

my_canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", click)
my_canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)
my_canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', release)



def undo():
    return

def redo()
    return

undo_btn = Button(root, text="Undo", command=undo)
undo_btn.pack()
redo_btn = Button(root, text="Redo", command=undo)
redo_btn.pack()

my_canvas.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: You've presented some code, but you haven't asked a question. What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the information of the lines to be able to undo them an play them back. For the former action, you just need the line's ID on the canvas. For the latter, you'll also need its coordinates. You can use a `dataclasses.dataclass()` to store the line information.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
my_canvas = Canvas(root, bg = "white", height=500, width=500, cursor="cross")
#Draw Line using mouse
coords = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "x2": 0, "y2": 0}
final = []
lines = []
deleted_lines = []


@dataclass
class Line:
    """Information about a drawn line."""

    id: int
    x: int
    y: int
    x2: int
    y2: int
    fill: str = 'red'
    width: int = 2

    def set_coords(self, x: int, y: int, x2: int, y2: int) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2


def click(e):
    coords["x"] = e.x
    coords["y"] = e.y
    id_ = my_canvas.create_line(coords["x"], coords["y"], coords["x"], coords["y"], fill='red', width=2)
    lines.append(Line(id_, coords["x"], coords["y"], coords["x"], coords["y"], fill='red', width=2))


def drag(e):
    coords["x2"] = e.x
    coords["y2"] = e.y
    line = lines[-1]
    my_canvas.coords(line.id, coords["x"], coords["y"], coords["x2"], coords["y2"])
    line.set_coords(coords["x"], coords["y"], coords["x2"], coords["y2"])


my_canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", click)
my_canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)


def undo():
    try:
        line = lines.pop()
    except IndexError:
        print('No lines to delete.')
        return

    deleted_lines.append(line)
    my_canvas.delete(line.id)


def redo():
    try:
        line = deleted_lines.pop()
    except IndexError:
        print('No deleted lines to redo.')
        return

    id_ = my_canvas.create_line(line.x, line.y, line.x2, line.y2, fill=line.fill, width=line.width)
    line = Line(id_, line.x, line.y, line.x2, line.y2, fill=line.fill, width=line.width)
    lines.append(line)
    

undo_btn = Button(root, text="Undo", command=undo)
undo_btn.pack()
redo_btn = Button(root, text="Redo", command=redo)
redo_btn.pack()

my_canvas.pack()

mainloop()
```